# What is this weed, native to south-western Ohio?

Tags: identification

What is the name of this plant/weed, found in south-western Ohio? They are fairly common and grow wildly. This particular one happens to just be growing dead-center in a pot:

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure it's from the Asteraceae family. We have it too in southeastern PA, but I never looked it up.

Comment: Does it produce a flower? What kind of conditions does it grow in?

Comment: Is this at this stage now? or is this an older photo?

Answer (score 1):

Initial reaction would be an Ironweed *Vernonia sp.*. New York Ironweed (Vernonia noveboracensis) is what I am familar with, and this looks simular. A lot of these are native and have very beautiful purple/pink flowers. They get fairly tall, but as the name suggests, they don't usually need support.